# How to blink chat window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two chat boxes. When I receive a new message from others, the chat box header that should blink. Here I used socket.js to send and receive the messages. For now I can blink one chat box. But I can not blink those chat boxes simultaneously using this timer. An example of the desired behaviour can be found in facebook chat window or hangouts chat window. I used JavaScript timer to blink this chat box for amount of time.

**JavaScript:**

```
function start(){
    clearTimeout(this.backgroundInterval);
    var $chatdivtoblink = $("#chat-header-window");
        this.backgroundInterval = setInterval(function(){
        $chatdivtoblink.toggleClass("backgroundRed");
     },1500)
}

function stop(){
   console.log("stop " + this.backgroundInterval);
   clearTimeout(this.backgroundInterval);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.backgroundRed {
     background: #000;
}
```

HTML sample code here:

```
<div class="chatElement chatBox" id="chatContainer-99"><div class="chat-header" id="chat-header-window"><div class="chat-header-content"></div></div>
```

The sample image here, please have a look at it:

[image]

**Here my real problem is** when a first chat window receives a message on inactive. i start a timer to blink chat window for amount of time. then second chat window receives a message and start timer. here is the problem which timer should i clear interval of timer? how do i start and stop timer for every individual chat window screen?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an ID, and from your description I'm inferring you have more than one element with the same ID. In this case, you should use a different attribute to target the chatboxes. For example, use a class:

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat-header-window">
```

**Javascript**

```
var $chatdivtoblink = $(".chat-header-window");
```

Comment: hello man. yes i used id to get chat window element. but i will have ten more members in the future like facebook chat window, how do i get there chat box id dynamically?

Comment: Assuming the 99 in your `id="chatContainer-99` is the chat box id. To get the element to blink. just change the selector to `$("#chatContainer-" + id + " .chat-header-window")`

Comment: yes, i got you. the problem is with blinking. assume person A,B ,C. person C sends message to A and person B sends message to A.  how do i start and stop timer object? please help me with it.

Comment: how do i have a look at the chat windows like OOPs Objects? i have to consider every chat window like object. because every object should work independently. when user mouse over on the chat box. timer should turn off. but my code does not act like that. please give me a good idea to implement it.

Comment: i have a method to close chat window. when i press "X" icon. the method will close all the chat windows. but it should close one window. this is another problem.